# JpegBitmapDecoder decode jpeg failed?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, jpeg

I'm using the following code to Decode Jpge image

```
UnmanagedMemoryStream^ mStream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream(_jpegDataBuff, _buffLength);
JpegBitmapDecoder^ decoder = gcnew JpegBitmapDecoder(mStream, BitmapCreateOptions::PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption::OnLoad);
BitmapSource^ bitmapSource = decoder->Frames[0];
```

I use the `bitmapSource` to display on control of WPF, but sometimes the the result as below

[image]

I have searched very much on internet, but I did not solve it yet!

Someone can help me?

Many Thanks,

T&T

Comment: From the looks of it I would say that either Jpeg source is incomplete or invalid. Are you sure you initialize `_jpegDataBuff` and `_buffLength` correctly?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: _jpegDataBuff is the data that parsed from IP Camera stream, maybe this caused by _jpegDataBuff is incomplete. How to check _jpegDataBuff data is conplete or not? And if it is incomplete, why JpegBitmapDecoder didn't throw any exception? Thank you!

Comment: I've explained details of my assumption in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it I would say that either JPEG source is incomplete or invalid. The only exceptions [JpegBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws are `ArgumentNullException` (stream is `null`) and `FileFormatException`. The file format is most probably detected by analyzing file header. The JIF/[JFIF file structure](http://www.jpeg.org/public/jfif.pdf) holds image description information in a relatively small header followed by a "raw" data.

I guess that decoder is built resilient to ignore invalid (rendered last before gray) and/or missing (rendered gray) blocks. I think the only way to detect is to either analyze final image (maybe checking that last 8x8px block doesn't have same color?)  or source (maybe counting data blocks?).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to check last 8x8 pixel as you said. But what does "maybe counting data blocks?" mean? Please explain to me more detail. Thank you!

Comment: @TTGroup that's because I don't know exact structure of a raw image data blocks. Maybe it's and easy to check, maybe not. Basically if each block have an *uncompressed* "size" field, it's trivial, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: so far, I don't know what reason caused this issue, but your answer may be suitable for this case. Thank you!